# How can my Phonegap-App open a Link in the Android Browser?

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

How can my Phonegap-App open a Link in the Android Browser? I tried many codes but they didn't worked.

Here is my actual Code: 
`<a href="http://store.spyfly.tk" target="_system">store.spyfly.tk</a>`

And the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="" type="text/xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE tag [
    <!ELEMENT tag (#PCDATA)>
]>
 <tag>
    <widget id="tk.spyfly.store.MANOS_VPlan" version="0.1.0">
        <name>MANOS-VPlan</name>
        <description>
            Vertretungspläne für das Martin-Andersen-Nexö-Gymnasium.
        </description>
        <author email="spyfly@pvpcrafter.tk" href="http://store.spyfly.tk">
            spyfly software
        </author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="WebViewBounce" value="true" />
    </widget>
</tag>
```

How should i do it. Please post some Examples.

---

Still opens inside the App.
My config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="" type="text/xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE tag [
    <!ELEMENT tag (#PCDATA)>
]>
 <tag>
    <widget id="tk.spyfly.store.MANOS_VPlan" version="0.1.0">
        <name>MANOS-VPlan</name>
        <description>
            Vertretungspläne für das Martin-Andersen-Nexö-Gymnasium.
        </description>
        <author email="spyfly@pvpcrafter.tk" href="http://store.spyfly.tk">
            spyfly software
        </author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="WebViewBounce" value="true" />
    </widget>
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
<access origin="*" browserOnly="true" />
</tag>
```

My index.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>MANOS-VPlan</title>

    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>


<a onclick="openThatLink()">store.spyfly.tk</a>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function openThatLink() {
            window.open('http://store.spyfly.tk', '_blank', 'location=yes');

}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What did i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a onclick="openThatLink()">store.spyfly.tk</a>

function openThatLink() {
            window.open('http://store.spyfly.tk', '_system', 'location=yes');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
window.open('http://store.spyfly.tk', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

In your config.xml include:

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
<access origin="*" browserOnly="true" />
```

The InAppBrowser is a web browser that displays in the app when calling window.open.

Refer [**Phonegap Doc**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html)

Comment: you have to use _system instead _blank if you want to use the native browser